# Knowing that $X$ independent of itself and $ \mathbb{E}[X^2] < \infty $, how to show that $X$ is a constant?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value

I have a random variable $X$ that is independent of itself.
How knowing that $$ \mathbb{E}[X^2] < \infty $$ is suppose to help me finding that $X$ is a constant.

I already found out that if $X$ is independent, $ \mathbb{P}(X \in A) = 0  $ or $ \mathbb{P}(X \in A) = 1 $. And I just pick $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and I have $\mathbb{P}(X \le x)^2 = \mathbb{P}(X \le x) \ge \mathbb{P}(X \le x) = 0  $ or $ \mathbb{P}(X \le x) = 1$

But how is it related to that expected value ? I really tried but I do not come with any ideas.

Many thanks ! If the question is ambiguous or unclear, please edit it :)

Comment: $E(X^2)=E(X)E(X)$ by Independence, so $Var(X)=0$. As a result, X is constant almost surely

Comment: An interesting generalization can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1913032)

Comment: @Evangelopoulos F. Please transform your comment into an answer.

Comment: You should say you have asked a cousin question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4025534)

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. OMG yes ! Thank you so much, I absolutely forgot about this rule ! Let me mark it as the answer :)

Comment: @JeanMarie Absolutely ! Thank you for mentioning that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comments, by the independence, we have that  $E(X^2)=E(X)E(X)$ and thus $Var(X)=0$. As a result, $X=E(X)$ (constant) almost surely.

Comment: What does "independent of itself" mean in terms of the definition via a joint distribution?

Comment: Well,  $X$ is independent  of it self iff $F_{X,X}(x,y) = F_X(x) F_Y(y) $ for all $x,y$. This is equivalent to saying that $ F_X(x) = (F_X(x))^2 $ for all $x$ which is equivalent to $F_X(x)=0 $ or $1$

Comment: I guess all sorts of odd things can happen with a degenerate distribution.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. : There's potentially consequential typo in your comment. It should say this:
$$
F_{X,X}(x,y) = F_X(x) F_X(y).
$$
No random variable called (capital) $Y$ is involved here. $\qquad$

Comment: @Aruralreader : $\qquad\uparrow\qquad$ See my comment above, and also this: To say that two real-valued random variables $X,Y$ are independent means that for sets $A,B\subseteq\mathbb R,$ the events $\big[ X\in A\big]$ and $\big[ Y\in B\]$ are independent. $\qquad$